# Duplicate List records

Tags: sharepoint-2007, unique, no-duplicates

How do I avoid entering the same kind of data from the same users in sharepoint list?

Any directions please
Hari Gillala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No luck going the easy way with Sharepoint 2007. With Sharepoint 2010 you have the choice to make values unique (see [SharePoint 2010 – Enforce Unique Values](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/jennifer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=03eb5002-db5e-4f06-bd2d-3b7b00d3de82&ID=45)).

With Sharepoint 2007 you have to do that programmatically using an EventReceiver. See following post for lot's of information: [How to avoid duplicate record depending on the field in customlist](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/3a6342b3-ce06-4be1-af0d-7daf12ca4d51)